# How to move system from Digital Ocean to Amazon Lightsail?

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-lightsail

I set up a droplet on Digital Ocean and have installed everything on it such as Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx, Node JS, Python, MongoDB, etc. I would like to move to AWS Lightsail. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct push pull button to move your digital ocean droplet to a Lightsail server. Cloud providers are never going to provide that so as to capitalize on customer Lock-ins.

You have to spin up a new lightsail server (probably Ubuntu 18.04) and install the corresponding versions of Nodejs, pyhton etc. one by one.

If you have actual data in the database you have to actually download it and again upload it as pointed out by @David G. In this case you can also use mlabs or any other Mongodb server provider, which would separately manage your databse for you. It makes your work much simpler if wanna move to another cloud provider later on and if this is a personal project their free versions would do the work for you.

You can also see the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/downloading-snapshots-into-local-machines. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The old fashion way :)

You'll have to download the applications & data from the old system and upload it to the new system.

Comment: I have Node JS, MongoDB installed on the old server. How can I move those?